# Android dialog : Is there a way to make background android UI clickable while dialog is displayed?

Tags: android, dialog, libgdx

Currently, I am using Libgdx for making app with lots of animation. I am trying to use android Dialog for showing paragraph with html tags through Interface. While,  I can change dim color of background UI back to normal with following code.

```
paragraphDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Is there anything I can do to make background UI work? (Button click, textview focus etc)

And, I have tried GlyphLayout of Libgdx for paragraph. It frequently crashes & also doesn't support html tags. I am using dialogs, as it is pretty easy to use xml layout easily with dialogs. If there are any other options, Please suggest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your dialog is blocking the entire screen, doesn't matter if the edges/background are somewhat transparent or not 100% alpha, it is still the view that is currently on top. therefor, you can't click on it directly.

i think the best way to achieve your goal is with a fragment. not a dialog.

Comment: I had no idea that the dialog blocks entire screen. Ya, I had fragment on my mind, but I was trying to find some easy way. Looks like, i have to dive in fragment. 
Thanks bro. :)