# button click outside of dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I've 2 buttons in my layout. First shows toast and another shows dialog. I want to be able to click the first button and show toast, even when dialog is showing. At present when I touch the first button (for first time), the dialog gets dismissed and when I again touch the first button (for second time), then the toast shows. What I want is to show the toast on the first click. Is it possible?

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sam.myregistrationapplication.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:text="close dialog"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:text="show dialog"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn1, btn2;
    Dialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                pDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.alertdialog);


                pDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);



                Button dialogButton = (Button) pDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn3);

                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                pDialog.show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: count click number at first

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android dialog : Is there a way to make background android UI clickable while dialog is displayed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932536/android-dialog-is-there-a-way-to-make-background-android-ui-clickable-while-di)

Answer (score 0):

If Diologue is Showing that time you are not able to click on any button on your activity. Second thing is that if you don't want to dismissed your dialogue until your task completed then use below line -

```
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

use two buttons

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="com.sam.myregistrationapplication.MainActivity">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="50dp"
            android:text="close dialog"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_margin="50dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="show dialog"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

now show second button on click of first button and hide first button,
same as show first button on click of second button and hide second button. try this and put the events you want to do on click of first and second buttons.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button btn1, btn2;
        Dialog pDialog;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
         btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);

         btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }
         });


        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              pDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
              pDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
              pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.alertdialog);
    pDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);



            Button dialogButton = (Button) pDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn3);

            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                 }
              });

              pDialog.show();

          }
       });

    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to make any button's visibility gone. I just want to be able to click the first button while showing a pop-up @anurag